# Does the "accumulate" method in AggregateFunction executes concurrently?

Tags: flink-sql

I am trying to aggregate some data using AggregateFunction in flink sql. This is my code:

```
public class SlideWindowHotNumAgg extends AggregateFunction<String, List<Map<String, String>>> {
    public static final String HOT_NUM_DELIMITER = ":";

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param acc the accumulator which contains the current
     *            aggregated results
     * @return hotNum:rowtimeEnd:hotNum:rowtimeEnd:hotNum:rowtimeEnd
     */
    @Override
    public String getValue(List<Map<String, String>> acc) {
        String res = "";
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(acc)) {
            return res;
        }

        return acc.stream()
                .map(m -> String.join(HOT_NUM_DELIMITER, m.getOrDefault(HOT_NUM, "0"), m.getOrDefault(ROWTIME_END, "0")))
                .reduce((a, b) -> String.join(HOT_NUM_DELIMITER, a, b))
                .orElse(res);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, String>> createAccumulator() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void accumulate(List<Map<String, String>> acc, Map<String, String> req) {
        acc.add(req);
    }

    public void retract(List<Map<String, String>> acc, Map<String, String> req) {
        acc.remove(req);
    }

    public void merge(List<Map<String, String>> acc, Iterable<List<Map<String, String>>> it) {
        for (List<Map<String, String>> i : it) {
            acc.addAll(i);
        }
    }

}
```

The ArrayList(which is used as an Accumulator in the code) is not thread-safe. Does the "accumulate" method executes concurrently?